# mailto link using computed property not loading full message body

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mailto

The mailto link is properly loading the recipients and subject but it seems to cut off the email body as a very short length. My email is a total of 1500 characters, so I am below the mailto limit. The email seems to be cutting off the body around 200 characters.

I am attaching a computed property to the mailto string because I am using a package called "marked.js" which parses user input to markdown/html.

How do I go about fixing this issue? I have tried setting a new data property as "emailFormat" and on page mount the email body is run through the marked package and then set as a data property. I assumed this would fix the issue because now I am just attaching a string to the mailto body, but this has not worked and i still end up with an incomplete email body.

computed property that takes in the api response data and runs through the marked package

```
letterContentToHtml() {
                if (this.formData.letterContent != null) {
                    return marked(this.formData.letterContent); // marked is package to parse user input to markdown/html. 
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            },
```

template section that displays the content and a button that includes the mailto href

```
<p class="email-content-data" v-html="letterContentToHtml"></p>
<v-btn class="send-form-btn"
            :disabled="!campaignFormValid || this.emailRecepients == ''"
            elevation="12"
            color="primary"
            target="_blank" 
            :href="mailToString"
            @click="updateCampaignList">
                Send Email!
        </v-btn>
```

mailto computed property

```
mailToString() {
                return "mailto:"+this.formData.emailList+"?subject="+this.formData.subject+"&body="+this.emailContent;
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must URL-encode your data before assigning it to the HREF property of a hyperlink/anchor tag:

```js
mailToString()
{
  return "mailto:" + encodeURIComponent(this.formData.emailList) + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(this.formData.subject) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(this.emailContent);
},
```

Otherwise it might interfer with some reserved characters, e.g. `?` or `=` or `&` or some Unicode character.

Comment: Ok but this now messes up for formatting. I am passing a string with things like "%0D%0A" so the email body is properly formatetted and spaced out. If i use encodeURIComponent that breaks the format and displays these characters

Comment: If you have already URL-encoded all components - email addresses, subject and body - then you don't need to encode them twice. But everything in the HREF attribute (after `mailto:`) must be a valid URL. You can try with a body of symbol `B` repeated 300 times to confirm for yourself that it is not cut off at the 200th symbol.